# Tomcat serving static content with directory listings

Tags: apache, localhost, tomcat, deployment

I have Tomcat 7 configured to serve static contents from a directory:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" name="localhost">
    ...
    <Context docBase="/var/projectA/static" path="/projectA/" />
</Host>
```

This is available at `localhost:8080/projectA/`. Is it possible to somehow enable directory listings for this context?

I know it's possible to do this with Apache in front of Tomcat, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Convert your directory `/var/projectA/static` to a simple application:

- create a directory `WEB-INF/`
- in `WEB-INF/` create the file *web.xml* with this content:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
> <web-app>
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>DirectoryListing</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>listings</param-name>
>         <param-value>true</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>DirectoryListing</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> </web-app>
> ```

This way the directory listing is only active for your specified context and not global.